# How to improve question acceptance when many possible answers are available?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

I know it can be hard to control what answers get accepted, yet I see that in many cases the accepted answer is either:

1. The first answer that works
2. The answer with either more detail explanations or full coding solution.

while I think such answers should be rewarded with up-votes, it is not always the case that they are the correct or best according to computer science theory or good software discipline ...etc

I wonder, is there an evaluation system applied at SOF to see what are the indicators of an accepted answer, is it the higher votes, any solution that works, the answer with most edits...etc? Any work going on to improve this with gamification tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Accepting an answer is an action taken solely by the user who asked the question, in their own time and at their own discretion. There is no "evaluation system" or any sort of automation in place. In the same vein, there isn't much that can or should be done in terms of gamification.

If you're simply asking about a rule of thumb, then there isn't much of that either; pick whichever you feel is more deserving of the acceptance. For example, should the better answer be rewarded greatly, or do you prefer to pick the answer that worked for you? That's something you will have to decide for yourself, and is something you don't have to answer to anyone else for (unless you have *really* questionable judgment...). I can say however that the number of edits is not a good indicator of anything, really.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That makes sense actually. The user-first model makes sense and is reasonable giving him/her the power to accept the answer. Thanks